# Dynamic LINQ (to objects): Substituting a object name in a query from a list of object names (string)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a good LINQ query that is working well, it returns a result set, each result set inherits from MyBase.

I need to substitute AbcTransport by doing a kind of loop through of collection of strings I have. These strings are actually the object names (classes)

```
 MyBase testItem = from x in AbcTransport
                     from y in x.SolidItems
                     where y.Classified == otherObject.Classified 
                     select x;
```

This will cut down on the amount of code I need to write.

I think this is possible with Dynamic Linq, but I am unsure where to start.

Imagine I have currently about 26 objects like AbcTransport that are all named different but all inherit from MyBase. The property I am interested in is actually on MyBase. If I could do a kind of Loop using Dynamic linq I wouldn't have to write my query 26 times and also would make in maintainable as when I add more objects I only have to add the object name into my collection and that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put that query inside a generic method?

```
MyBase Get<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : MyBase
{
    MyBase testItem = from x in list
                      from y in x.SolidItems
                      where y.Classified == otherObject.Classified 
                      select x;
    return testItem;
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
var result1 = Get(AbcTransport);
var result2 = Get(DefTransport);
```